# Possible to make an array of an array?

Tags: java

Is it possible to make an array of an array? What I am trying to do is basically make a an array of another array without duplicates.

For example:

```
String[] colour ={"blue","blue","red","blue","red","red","orange","yellow","purple","green","blue"};
```

and then make a new array from String[] colour into:

```
String[] uniqueColour = {"blue","red","orange","yellow","purple","green"}
```

using a function and without just declaring it? Cause lets say I change all the values of String[] Colour and turn it into

```
String[] Fruits = {"Apple","Banana","Orange","Tomato","Apple","Banana"}
```

then without doing or changing anything else the function should create

```
String[] uniqueColour ={"Apple","Banana","Orange","Tomato"}
```

Does such a thing exist? Sorry for the trouble. And I'm new to java as well.

A thank you to anyone who can contribute or help me out.

EDIT:
Okay so by using this: - Thanks to Doorknob's answer

```
Set<String> uniqueSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(colour));
String[] uniqueColours = uniqueSet.toArray(new String[0]);
```

how would I then try to display it as:

```
Blue
Red
Yellow
Green
Purple
ect
```

instead of `[Blue,Red,Yellow,Green,Purple,etc]`

Comment: "*then without doing or changing anything else the function should create*" - Then how do you think things are changed?

Comment: *Is it possible to make an array of an array?* Yes , but what are you trying to achieve is very vague !

Comment: When we say "array of arrays" we mean a two-dimensional array -- an array where each element is another array.  You seem to be asking about removing duplicates, so your wording is quite confusing.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry guys I am terrible at explaining things I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Set` to remove duplicates:

```
Set<String> uniqueSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(colour));
String[] uniqueColours = uniqueSet.toArray(new String[0]);
```

To display it in the way you wanted:

```
for (String s : uniqueColors) System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: How would I display the String[] Unique Colours? By that I mean instead of it showing up as [blue,red,orange,yellow,purple,green] I want to display it as `Blue\nRed\nOrange\nYellow\nPurple\nGreen`

Comment: @Leo Why the unaccept? Did it not work?

Comment: @Leo Is there anything wrong with this solution?